# Вывод элементов массивов попарно

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть два массива:

```
int[] a = {1, 3, 5};
int[] b = {2, 4, 6};
```

Необходимо вывести их содержимое в консоль таким образом *(чтобы элементы чередовались и через каждые два элемента был перевод строки)*:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Сейчас я сделала так:

```
int[] a = {1, 3, 5};
int[] b = {2, 4, 6};
int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i];
    count++;
}
for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
    c[count++] = b[j];
}
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
}
```

Однако вывод теперь такой: `135246`. Что мне исправить в коде, чтобы получить правильный вывод?

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужен просто вывод, то зачем вам дополнительный масив? Пройдитесь в одном цикле по обоим массивам сразу, выводя текущие значения. System.out.println(a[i]+" "+b[i])

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] a = {1, 3, 5};
int[] b = {2, 4, 6};

IntStream
        // обходим индексы массива, предполагаем,
        // что массивы одинаковой длины
        .range(0, a.length)
        // собираем элементы двух массивов в одну
        // строку с разделителем пробелом
        .mapToObj(i -> a[i] + " " + b[i])
        // вывод построчно
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```